# TypeScript Blob : Get error as Argument of type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. for new Blob declare

Tags: typescript, blob

I am trying to send binary data in POST request in XHR using type script. 
When I try `new Blob (myData, {type:"text/plain"})` get error as :

> Argument of type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Any pointers?

Comment: Did you try `new Blob (myData, "text/plain")`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

```
var debug = {hello: "world"};
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(debug, null, 2)], {type : 'application/json'});
```

This works fine in the console so I'm assuming there is something wrong with your parameter "myData". The first parameter of the constructor should be

> An Array of ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob, USVString objects, or
>   a mix of any of such objects, that will be put inside the Blob.

Assuming your myData is a string, you could try the following:

```
new Blob ([myData], {type:"text/plain"});
```